# How to close dev container connection on remote server

Tags: vscode-remote

In have a server on which I have launched a Dev Container to develop a NodeJS application.

I am using VS Code to connect to this server via the "Remote - SSH" extension. Once connected to the server, I use the "Remote Explorer" extension to connect to the Dev Container which is running on that remote machine. That all works perfectly.
How do I exit from the Dev Container on the remote server without completely closing the connection to the host server?

The only option I seem to have is "Close Remote Connection" from the "Remote - SSH" connection options. This obviously kills the connection to the remote server: which is really rude if you only want to exit the container on the remote server.
Does anybody know an elegant way to exit the container, but leave the connection to the remote server in tact?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the [VSCode Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)
   MacOS: <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
   Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Select **`Dev Containers: Reopen Folder in SSH`**

[Screenshot of VSCode command palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzvkV.png)